# Does the tr element get "clickable" in its class attribute?

Tags: angular

In the code snippet below, the first column is a clickable (^ and v) to open and close an accordion style of rows. This cell gets the "clickable" value in the class attribute. All other cells, when clicked, open up a new page (processed by the getProfileDetail function). But the tr class attribute does not get the clickable value. I'm using .clickable in my css to show the cursor: pointer. The click events work. My trouble is getting the visual correct. The point shows on the first cell, but does not show for the rest of the row.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a better way to go about what I am trying to do?

(For what it's worth, the rows that are displayed when the accordion is open are not clickable. That code is not displayed below.)

```
<tr class="info-row" [ngClass]="{even: even}"
    (click)="getProfileDetail(searchResult.id)">
    <td ngid="pr-col-accordion"  [ngClass]="{even: even, clickable: searchResults.records.length>1}"
    (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); searchResult.records.length > 1 ? searchResult.opened = !searchResult.opened : false">
        <i [ngClass]="{'material-icons': searchResult.records.length > 1, opened: searchResult.opened}"></i>
    </td>
    <td>{{searchResult.id}}</td>
    <td>{{searchResult.name}}</td>
    <td>{{searchResult.contact}}</td>
    <td>{{searchResult.records[0].name}}</td>
    <td>
        <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could you host a plnkr ? I think I know why but I can't try to be sure

Comment: Actually, I think I just figure it out. In the `tr`, I need `[ngClass]="even: even, clickable: true"`

Answer (score 0):

In the  element, the answer is to add

```
<tr class="info-row" [ngClass]="{even: even, clickable: true}" ...
```